# Correlation between correlations

Tags: probability, asymptotics, statistical-inference, central-limit-theorem

Suppose
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
X_i \\ Y_i \\ Z_i
\end{pmatrix} \sim N\left(\begin{pmatrix}
\mu_X \\ \mu_Y \\ \mu_Z
\end{pmatrix}, \sigma^2\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \rho_{XY} & \rho_{XZ} \\ \rho_{XY} & 1 & \rho_{YZ}  \\ \rho_{XZ} & \rho_{YZ} & 1
\end{pmatrix}\right)
\end{align*}
The sample correlation estimator
\begin{align*}
\widehat{\rho}_{XY} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_iY_i - n \overline{X}\overline{Y}}{(n-1)S_XS_Y}, \qquad S_X = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - \overline{X})^2}
\end{align*}
is known to have [approximate distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_transformation)
\begin{align*}
\text{arctanh}(\widehat{\rho}_{XY}) \overset{\mathcal{D}}{\approx} N\left(\text{arctanh}(\rho_{XY}), \frac{1}{\sqrt{n-3}}\right) 
\end{align*}
or, more correctly,
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{n}[\text{arctanh}(\widehat{\rho}_{XY})-\text{arctanh}(\rho_{XY})] \overset{\mathcal{D}}{\rightarrow} N\left(0, 1\right)
\end{align*}
and an analogous statement can be made about $\widehat{\rho}_{YZ}$. From there, if we really wanted, we can apply the delta method to derive the asymptotic distributions of $\widehat{\rho}_{XY}, \widehat{\rho}_{YZ}$.

In fact, we can slightly rewrite the previous results into the form
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{n}\begin{pmatrix}
\text{arctanh}(\widehat{\rho}_{XY}) - \text{arctanh}(\rho_{XY}) \\
\text{arctanh}(\widehat{\rho}_{YZ}) - \text{arctanh}(\rho_{YZ}) \
\end{pmatrix}\overset{\mathcal{D}}{\rightarrow} N\left(\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & a \\ a & 1\end{pmatrix}\right)
\end{align*}
**My Question:** What is $a$? That is, the asymptotic covariance between $\widehat{\rho}_{XY}$ and $\widehat{\rho}_{YZ}$?